# Backslashes in duplicate titles break inserted links

Tags: bug, status-completed, markdown, duplicate-questions, title

If a question's title has a backslash, inserted "possible duplicate" links [are](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2376240/sql-exception-when-transferring-project-from-usb-to-c) [broken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2430022/sql-exception-when-transferring-project-from-usb-to-c-closed) (check revision histories, both have since been fixed).  I'm not familiar with all of the markdown parsing, but the only significantly affected cases appear to be Windows paths, as it would otherwise be rare to end the title with a backslash.

The solution appears to be as simple as replacing \ with \\.

Comment: related "possible duplicate" bugginess (didn't seem exactly the same bug so i posted separately): http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44366/url-in-duplicate-titles-wonkify-related-links

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, I'll escape slashes.