# URL in duplicate titles wonkify related links

Tags: bug, status-completed, markdown, duplicate-questions, title

Very similar to [@Gnome's earlier question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44319/backslashes-in-duplicate-titles-break-inserted-links).  The markdown for automagically-inserted duplicate links breaks if the duplicate contains a URL in the title.

[In this case](https://superuser.com/questions/125079/how-does-http-to-work-closed), markdown splits the URL into its own link, and text earlier in the title is given the correct link to the duplicate question.  The URLs work, but it looks wonky -- the question link doesn't span the entire question title, and users aren't expecting multiple links there.

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does http://to./ work?](https://superuser.com/questions/78408/how-does-http-to-work)

link code:

```
[How does http://to./ work?](https://superuser.com/questions/78408/how-does-http-to-work)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, I'll remove any absoluteness from URLs here.

Comment: erm.  this doesn't appear completed; same problem persists.  see example link in the question.

Comment: @quack fix is for future closings, not this one, which predates the fix.

Comment: ok, thx for clarifying.  i'll tweak this one to "hxxp" so that link shows up correctly.