# Automatic "possible duplicate" message strips "http://" from duplicate title

Tags: bug, status-completed, hyperlinks, markdown, duplicate-questions

I noticed something when [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7693598/using-instead-of-protocol) was closed as a duplicate of this one:

> [Is it valid to replace http:// with // in a <script src=“…”>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/550038/is-it-valid-to-replace-http-with-in-a-script-src-http)

The "possible duplicate" message stripped the `http://` from the title like this:

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it valid to replace  with // in a <script src=“…”>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/550038/is-it-valid-to-replace-http-with-in-a-script-src-http)

It's not hidden or anything, it's just not there:

> `Is it valid to replace  with // in a &lt;script src=&ldquo;&hellip;&rdquo;&gt;?`

I always thought it seemed weird that the "possible duplicate" text is inserted into the actual post body instead of something more like the "Linked" section, but that's a different concern altogether I suppose.

Seems low-priority, but could be a sign of other potential issues and seemed unintentional, so I figured I'd report it as I didn't see any mention of it.

Comment: Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions."  Now they have two problems.

Comment: @blah: [Hmm, who would ever think that?](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/03/if-you-like-regular-expressions-so-much-why-dont-you-marry-them.html)

Answer (score 3):

This was indeed the quickfix for the [issue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44366/url-in-duplicate-titles-wonkify-related-links) that Shog9 found. Back then, the Markdown converter had link-within-link issues, where

```
[the http://somewhere thing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relevant_article)
```

would be converted to

```
<a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relevant_article">the http://somewhere thing</a>
```

and *then the autolinker would kick in*, doing this:

```
<a href="...">the <a http://somewhere">somewhere</a></a>
```

which is all kinds of wrong.

I did however [fix](http://code.google.com/p/markdownsharp/source/detail?r=7869b26976a3e5d9ff880d16125580a2ee40064e) that issue a long time ago, so this workaround isn't necessary anymore. It's removed in the next build.

Answer (score 1):

This [probably *is* intentional](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44366/url-in-duplicate-titles-wonkify-related-links) - since proper URLs are actually converted into links when they appear in post body text, a title with a URL in it would suddenly be a link when inserted into the duplicate box.

Stripping off the http:// is a pretty easy work-around. Except in this case, there's nothing *after* it...