# Auto "possible duplicate" comment should use trimmed title?

Tags: bug, status-completed, duplicate-questions, automatic-comments

It is apparent that [this has been brought up before](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79729/auto-generated-duplicate-links-dont-trim-titles), and fixed - so there shouldn't be any 'bad' titles; but evidently there are:

[image]

As seen, the whitespace is still lurking around, breaking the neat link.

Answer (score 8):

I have now created a centralized method that creates a markdown link given the title and the link, both for ["real" post Markdown](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44319/backslashes-in-duplicate-titles-break-inserted-links) and for the comment MarkdownMini like in this case, and (hopefully) this method takes care of all these edge cases that can appear in this back-and-forth conversion (and there are quite a few of those edge case). So from the next build on, both the "possible duplicate" auto-comments and the "Possible duplicates" blocks at the top of a closed question should look correct. Note that this isn't retroactive; it's only true for newly generated comments/edits.

And the best thing: That method even has unit tests, so it can't possibly have any bugs!*

<sub>*If someone thinks that's too bold a statement, I suggest watching [Rick Astley's talk](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oHg5SJYRHA0) on DDD (delusion-driven development).</sub>

Comment: Great, thanks. I'll keep my eyes peeled for any problems.